# failed client connection to minifabric blockchain

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

i set up a blockchain network using docker and pulling the latest minifabric image, which sets up it's directory (minifabric/vars etc), my chaincode works but i cannot connect to the blockchain with the main.js app (node), i get all sorts of error that i can post if needed but my main question is whether i should use the fabric-network module (which seems to be deprecated?) or the fabric-gateway module.
Any help? I would like a default main.js which is currently working with current updated modules and so on

I tried running the default main.js which docker pulls along the minifabric image, i tried the main.js found in the fabric-network module documentation as well as the fabric-network one but none seem to work, i will post errors as soon as i know which is the current utilized and working module